# getopt_long the second option gets recognised as argument of first option

Tags: c, getopt-long

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];
    FILE *log;
    //int cp;
    int port_no;

    while(1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[]=
        {
            {"port", required_argument, 0, 'p'},
            {"log", required_argument, 0, 'l'},
        };

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:l:",long_options,NULL);

        if(c==-1)
        {
            break;
        }
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'p':
                if (optarg)
                {
                    port_no = atoi(optarg);
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Usage --port= port number\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'l':
                if(optarg)
                {
                    log = fopen(optarg,"w");
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Usage --log= logfilename\n");
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                //fprintf(stderr,"Argument no recognised\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `./client --port --log` it recognizes `--log` as the port number argument, and when I run `./client --log --port`, it recognizes `--port` as the log file argument and creates a file named `--port`.

Why does this happen? Isn't `--` a special character in `getopt_long()`?

Comment: For better or worse, that is the way that `getopt_long()` is designed — and plain `getopt()` works analogously.  The `--` string (on its own) can also be the argument to an option that takes an argument, rather than marking the end of the options as it normally does.  That is, `./client --port -- -log -- -- --log string` provides the string `--` as the argument to `--port` and to `--log`; the third occurrence does mark the end of the options, so the second `--log` is a 'filename' (non-option) argument, as is `string`.

Answer (score 2):

`port` and `log` are both declared as `required_argument`. Thus it looks the argument behind `--log`, so `--port` is treated as the `arg` not `option`.

The proper usage would be something like `./client --port 8080 --log file.log`.